# How to implement the Observer pattern with Java RMI?

Tags: java, rmi, observer-pattern

I have a client that starts a long running process on the server. At regular intervals, I'd like to show the user what's happening in the background. The most simple approach is to poll the server but I'm wondering if there wasn't a way to implement the Observer pattern for this. Unfortunately, I'm using RMI to talk to the server and I fear that I have to turn my client into an RMI server for this.

Is there another way that I'm missing?

Comment: I am trying to do this as well and I came to the same conclusion ... rmi kinda sucks! :)

Comment: https://sandny.com/2017/05/18/java-rmi-observer-slider/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://sites.google.com/site/jamespandavan/Home/java/sample-remote-observer-based-on-rmi

Answer (score 3):

RMI can in general support two way communication. (And yeah, RMI is a PITA to set up, and do anything else with.)

However, the HTTP transport that works over a CGI script(!) does not support it.

Comment: Is that still true when I start the server in my code with LocateRegistry.createRegistry() (instead of using the executable supplied by Sun)?

Comment: +1 for "(And yeah, RMI is a PITA to set up, and do anything else with.)" Please tell my school that.

Answer (score 2):

Consolidating all the answers here, I implemented 2 way RMI between client and server with server exposing its stub using Registry

1. The client gets a stub of the server from rmi registry
2. Then the client puts its stub as Observer to the server's addObserver  method
3. The server notifies the clients using this stub

The following code will gives a better idea

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.net.*;

import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory;
import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory;

interface ReceiveMessageInterface extends Remote
{
    /**
     * @param x
     * @throws RemoteException
     */
    void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException;

    /**
     * @param observer
     * @throws RemoteException
     */
    void addObserver(Remote observer) throws RemoteException;
}

/**
 * 
 */
class RmiClient extends UnicastRemoteObject
{
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static public void main(String args[])
    {
        ReceiveMessageInterface rmiServer;
        Registry registry;
        String serverAddress = args[0];
        String serverPort = args[1];
        String text = args[2];
        System.out.println("sending " + text + " to " + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort);
        try
        { // Get the server's stub
            registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress, (new Integer(serverPort)).intValue());
            rmiServer = (ReceiveMessageInterface) (registry.lookup("rmiServer"));

            // RMI client will give a stub of itself to the server
            Remote aRemoteObj = (Remote) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new RmiClient(), 0);
            rmiServer.addObserver(aRemoteObj);

            // call the remote method
            rmiServer.receiveMessage(text);
            // update method will be notified
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NotBoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void update(String a) throws RemoteException
    {
        // update should take some serializable object as param NOT Observable
        // and Object
        // Server callsbacks here
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
class RmiServer extends Observable implements ReceiveMessageInterface
{
    String address;
    Registry registry;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException
    {
        System.out.println(x);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(x + "invoked me");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void addObserver(final Remote observer) throws RemoteException
    {
        // This is where you plug in client's stub
        super.addObserver(new Observer()
        {
            @Override
            public void update(Observable o,
                Object arg)
            {
                try
                {
                    ((RmiClient) observer).update((String) arg);
                }
                catch (RemoteException e)
                {

                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @throws RemoteException
     */
    public RmiServer() throws RemoteException
    {
        try
        {
            address = (InetAddress.getLocalHost()).toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("can't get inet address.");
        }
        int port = 3232;
        System.out.println("this address=" + address + ",port=" + port);
        try
        {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            registry.rebind("rmiServer", this);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {
            System.out.println("remote exception" + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    static public void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            RmiServer server = new RmiServer();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Base on your code, the RmiClient class can be use on the server when the RmiServer class implement the addObserver methed. Is that the RmiClient class defined in both the client and the server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're missing anything. The only two ways are to either periodically call the server and check the status (polling) or register a callback which the server periodically calls (your client must expose a method).  IMO, polling is a perfectly reasonable way to handle this.